# Getting terminal access on old, strange hardware

Tags: hp-ux

I have an old, esoteric piece of special-purpose hardware (it's a HP logic analyser system). It's running HP-UX (because OLD).

Right now, it boots right into an X session with the special logic-analyser software running.

I'd like to get to a terminal prompt, so I can poke around with the internals (out of curiosity).

Given that this is basically a PC with some specialty hardware, what are the ways you can break out of a mildly locked-down X-session? I do have hardware access to the machine, but I'd like to avoid having to pull the disk or make boot-floppies for the thing (I don't have any other devices with floppy drives!).

Comment: Based on my experience with HP lab equipment (and sorry to say HP-UX) I highly doubt it. Even though it's got unix under the hood, they liked to make their devices turnkey and hid the OS so it would act like a toaster. You might find some RS-232 pins on the motherboard for diagnostic purposes which just might get you a console. Happy hunting.

Comment: @msw - It boots verbosely, and it uses a plain-old keybard and mouse. Also, there *is* a filesystem browser. It seems like it would be pretty hard to expose all that and not have some way to get to a terminal.

Comment: have you tried searching the filesystem for xterm or terminal or similar?

Comment: @cas - I can find `sh` and `csh`, but the file manager doesn't have any way of executing the binaries.

Comment: Can it copy or move files?  You could replace some other binary with copy of xterm and then find a way to run it... (inspired by "copy cmd.exe to sethc.exe" hack)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at an HP-UX CDE VUE Desktop here is what you would do:

1. Hold Right click on a blank desktop space using your ancient HIL pointing device
2. Select "New Window"
3. Release the right clicker

This brings up a blank terminal window logged in as the current user.

**-OR-**

From the `File Manager` use the `File` menu and select `Open Terminal`

**-OR-**

In the `Application Manager` under `Desktop tools`:

Select any of the following:

- `Hpterm`
- `Terminal Console`
- `Xterm`

(Each terminal has slight differences. The custom HPTerm has some more modern features.)

**If all that fails:**

No matter how locked down the Desktop is, it's still a Unix computer. You can boot in to single user mode by interrupting the boot cycle.

When you first see video you need to tap `ESC` to interupt the boot cycle. This brings up the ISL prompt.

Enter `HPUX -is` at the ISL prompt to tell it to boot HPUX in single user mode.